# Check any non null values available in DICTIONARY c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Can we check a Dictionary<string,string> contains at-least one non null value easily ?

I can iterate through each items of dictionary

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in productsDictionary)
        {
            if(!string.IsnullOrEmpty(kvp.Value)){
             //At least one non null value exists;
             break;
            }
        }
```

Without looping is any way to get it done? I can see

```
  Dictionary.ContainsValue(<aspecificvalue>)  // not found a way to do not null check here
```

Comment: I would venture a guess that any alternate method you find would, under the hood, actually just be a loop, just like the one you wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary.Values` and LINQ:

```
bool containsOneNotNullValue = productsDictionary.Values.Any(s => s != null);
```

But of course this also uses a loop to find that out, the loop is just hidden in a method.

Comment: Can we handle the null or whitespace checks Like String IsNullOrEmpty with this one

Comment: @Mat yes you can.

Comment: Important to note that `Any` does break at first occurrence that match the predicate so it can be very fast if nulls are close to the beginning. Complexity of maximum N

Comment: @Mat: You can use any method there, you could even call your own method that returns a `bool` if you want. I just showed what you have asked for("at-least one non null value").

Comment: @Mat in the `Any` it require a predicate which must return a `bool`. A `true` will make it exit and a `false` will make it evaluate the next element. The format is `Any(s => { return true;  })` replace the `true` with any logic you want and use `s` as the string value it's evaluating

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that by LINQ.

For example,

```
var productsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
productsDictionary.Add("A", "uppercase letter A");
productsDictionary.Add("c", "lowercase letter C");
productsDictionary.Add("d", null);


var result = productsDictionary.Any(e => ! string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```